# Calculating Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: c++, fibonacci

that displays exactly 8 (eight) Fibonacci numbers starting and ending from user-specified numbers (program’s input). For example, if a user inputs index 3 and 10, then numbers (values) F3 - F10 are shown on the screen. Erroneous user’s input (e.g. negative number) or a smaller ending number than the first, should lead to warning and automatic repetition of the input.

Comment: NNo TThansks... TTry SSomething and AAsk for HHelp if you GGet SSTuck.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for **problem solving**, whereas **problem** refers to some problem you encounter while trying to do something (in this case: calculating Fibonacci numbers). However, it's not a "do my work for me" site, so you should show specific code you've written, i.e. what you've tried, then add some notes on where your problem is or where specifically you need some help with.

Comment: @parkydr "can you do my homework for me?"

Comment: You should read the [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a small hint without doing all the work for you (as this seems to be some task for school, college, or university), here's how a Fibonacci number is defined:

```
f(0) = 0;
f(1) = 1;
f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
```

So in C++ this could be written like this:

```
int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

This of course can be further optimized and it's not necessarily the best approach. And it also includes possible errors, that might lead to stack overflows (hey, isn't that what this site is about? :)). So try to understand the code, then try to learn and improve it. Don't just copy & paste.

Comment: Obviously more than "Google?". :)